# Python and Windows shell namespace extensions

Tags: python, windows, api, filesystems, virtual

Do any modules exist for connecting Python to Windows shell namespace extensions? I'm looking at connecting a Python Virtual File System to Windows without the need of Dokan (as it can't run applications out of the drive). I've read that Windows shell namespace extensions might be able to do the trick, but I can't find a method for putting the two together.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!